# Deutron bound state problem (2 body problem)

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, potential-energy, atoms

In deutron if we calculate the potential depth for just the bound case (that is, taking the binding energy as zero), we get the minimum potential depth $25 \; Mev$. But when we consider binding energy of deutron as $2.2 \; Mev$, we get $38\;Mev$ potential depth.

Now, in this $38 \; Mev$ potential depth, the bound energy of deutron is  $2.2\; Mev$, so that for just the bound case it must have $35.8 \; Mev$ potential depth for the deutron to be a bound system.

Then why do we take 25 Mev for just bound case?

[Here](https://www.schandpublishing.com/books/higher-education/physics/nuclear-physics/9788121904131/) is a book reference.

Comment: I don't know a deutron. You mean deuteron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that $V_0-E_b=$constant, which is not the case. $E_b$, the energy of the bound state, is a complicated function of the maximum depth of the potential $V_0$ (it also depends on the shape of the potential). From a cursory look through some textbooks, I found the folowing transcendental equation relating the two (for a finite square well approximation to the deuteron potential),
$$k_1 \text{cot}(k_1R_0)=k_2R_0$$ 
where $\hbar k_1=\sqrt{2m(V_0-E)}$ is the momentum for a particle inside the square well and $\hbar k_2=\sqrt{2mE}$ is the momentum outside. Setting $k_2=0$ gives us the depth of the potential when the bound state energy eigenvalue is zero. There is no simple linear equation relating the two quantities you are comparing. All that you get from energy conservation is, $$E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}+V$$ and this certainly does not imply the relationship you are assuming.

Comment: In textbooks it is written that, the Depth of potential when bound state energy eigen value is zero, is the minimum potential required to achieve bound state of duetron(which comes about 25 Mev) .Now here lie the confusion, if I consider that in the bound state, the potential depth is about 38 Mev, and if I provide 2.2 Mev to the deutron nucleus, then the nucleons must get apart, so the minimum potential depth required shoud be 37.8 Mev, then what are these two different potential depth signify?

Comment: you put in a potential depth, and get a bound state as an output. if the depth of the potential is 25MeV, the nucleus is only marginally bound, i.e., a tiny perturbation will dismantle the state. if the potential depth is 38MeV, you need 2.2MeV to break apart the deuteron. for this potential, 35.8MeV does not signify much, it is the kinetic energy of a particle that is in that bound state, trapped in the well. it is not the potential depth.